# Loop two arrays at once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I do have an array with orders, each with a date. Like:

```
[
#<Order id: 1, date: '2019-10-07'>,
#<Order id: 2, date: '2019-10-08'>,
#<Order id: 3, date: '2019-10-10'>,
#<Order id: 4, date: '2019-10-10'>,
#<Order id: 5, date: '2019-10-12'>
]
```

I want to display it like this:

```
2019-10-05:
2019-10-06:
2019-10-07: id 1
2019-10-08: id 2
2019-10-09:
2019-10-10: id 3, id 4
2019-10-11:
2019-10-12: id 5
2019-10-13:
```

What is the best way to do this?

I can think of the following options:

1. `date_range.each do ...` and check if there are any corresponding orders on that date.
2. First sort the array of orders, then do `orders.each do ...` and check if there are any dates skipped.

Is there some 3rd way, that is walking through both arrays simultaneously? Like starting with the dates, when there is a corresponding order, start continue with the orders until there is a new date?

Comment: What's the starting day, where did you get `2019-10-05:` from? What's the ending date, where did you get `2019-10-13: ` from ?

Comment: As an example. probably going to use something like `3.months.ago..Date.today`.

Comment: `3.months.ago` doesn't have a `succ` method, so you cant iterate it with a range, you'll have to convert it to a date first. `3.months.ago.to_date` should work. See: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Range.html#class-Range-label-Custom+Objects+in+Ranges

Comment: 1. When you address comments that ask for clarification please edit your question rather than elaborating in comments. Questions should stand on their own; readers should not be expected to read through all the comments to understand what is being asked. 2. Are the elements of the array always in date order, as they are in the example? 3. Please no “probably going to use”. That’s like asking “what is `x + 2` when `x` probably equals `2`?”. Be precise and definite. 4. The title refers to a second array. Where is it?...

Comment: ...5. Whenever you give an example please attach a variable to all inputs: `arr = [#<Order id: 1,...]`, `start_date = ...`, `end_date = ...`.  That allows readers to reference those variable in answers and comments without having to define them.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what [Michael Kohl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58413739/3982562) and [arieljuod](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58413753/3982562) describe in their answers. First group your dates based on date, then loop through the dates and grab the groups that are relevant.

```
# mock
orders = [{id: 1, date: '2019-10-07'}, {id: 2, date: '2019-10-08'}, {id: 3, date: '2019-10-10'}, {id: 4, date: '2019-10-10'}, {id: 5, date: '2019-10-12'}]
orders.map!(&OpenStruct.method(:new))

# solution
orders = orders.group_by(&:date)
orders.default = []

date_range = Date.new(2019, 10, 5)..Date.new(2019, 10, 13)
date_range.map(&:iso8601).each do |date|
  ids = orders[date].map { |order| "id: #{order.id}" }.join(', ')
  puts "#{date}: #{ids}"
end
# 2019-10-05:
# 2019-10-06:
# 2019-10-07: id: 1
# 2019-10-08: id: 2
# 2019-10-09:
# 2019-10-10: id: 3, id: 4
# 2019-10-11:
# 2019-10-12: id: 5
# 2019-10-13:
#=> ["2019-10-05", "2019-10-06", "2019-10-07", "2019-10-08", "2019-10-09", "2019-10-10", "2019-10-11", "2019-10-12", "2019
```

Comment: Plain Ruby users should `require 'ostruct'` and `require 'date'`.

Comment: Good answer. It would be helpful to display what is `puts`'d, in part to show that you've tested.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Agreed, I've updated the question with the console output.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with something like this:

1. Group the array of orders by date: `lookup = orders.group_by(:date)`
2. Iterate over your date range, use date as key into `lookup`, so at least you don't need to traverse the `orders` array repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a mix of both:

```
# rearange your array of hashes into a hash with [date, ids] pairs
orders_by_date = {}
orders.each do |id, date|
  orders_by_date[date] ||= []
  orders_by_date[date] << id
end

# iterate over the range and check if the previous hash has the key
date_range.each do |date|
  date_s = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
  date_ids = orders_by_date.fetch(date_s, []).map { |x| "id: #{x}" }.join(', ')
  puts "#{date_s}: #{date_ids}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `group_by`. You can find the documentation at https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/group_by

```
grouped_orders = orders.group_by{|ords| ords[:date]}
```

```rb
(start_date..end_date).each do |order_date|
  puts order_date
  grouped_orders.fetch(order_date).map{|m| puts m.id}
end
```

Comment: This is incorrect. For one, you want `ords.date`, not `ords[:date]`. I suggest you test before posting.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, originally, the orders where hashes and not objects, that's why `ords[:date]` was used, the OP modified the question after the answers

Comment: @arieljuod, I see. Presumably that applies to you answer as well. I hate it when OP's change their questions, especially when it's done after answers have been posted. Not only is it a time-waster for those answering but it generally also renders their answers incorrect, even nonsensical.

Answer (score 0):

**Data**

We are given an array of instances of the class `Order`:

```
require 'date'

class Order
  attr_reader :id, :date
  def initialize(id,date)
    @id = id
    @date = date
  end
end

arr = ['2019-10-07', '2019-10-08', '2019-10-10', '2019-10-10', '2019-10-12'].
  map.each.with_index(1) { |s,i| Order.new(i, Date.iso8601(s)) }
  #=> [#<Order:0x00005a49d68ad8b8 @id=1,
  #      @date=#<Date: 2019-10-07 ((2458764j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>>,
  #    #<Order:0x00005a49d68ad6d8 @id=2,
  #      @date=#<Date: 2019-10-08 ((2458765j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>>,
  #    #<Order:0x00005a49d68ad3b8 @id=3,
  #      @date=#<Date: 2019-10-10 ((2458767j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>>,
  #    #<Order:0x00005a49d68ad138 @id=4,
  #      @date=#<Date: 2019-10-10 ((2458767j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>>,
  #    #<Order:0x00005a49d68aceb8 @id=5,
  #      @date=#<Date: 2019-10-12 ((2458769j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>>]
```

and start and end dates:

```
start_date = '2019-10-05'
end_date   = '2019-10-13'
```

**Assumption**

I assume that:

```
Date.iso8601(start_date) <= arr.first.date &&
  arr.first.date <= arr.last.date &&
  arr.last.date <= Date.iso8601(end_date)
  #=> true
```

There is no need for the elements of `arr` to be sorted by date.

**Code**

```
h = (start_date..end_date).each_with_object({}) { |d,h| h[d] = d + ':' }
arr.each do |inst|
  date = inst.date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
  h[date] += "#{h[date][-1] == ':' ? '' : ','} id #{inst.id}"
end
h.values
  #=> ["2019-10-05:",
  #    "2019-10-06:",
  #    "2019-10-07: id 1",
  #    "2019-10-08: id 2",
  #    "2019-10-09:",
  #    "2019-10-10: id 3, id 4",
  #    "2019-10-11:",
  #    "2019-10-12: id 5",
  #    "2019-10-13:"]
```

**Explanation**

The first step is to construct the hash `h`:

```
h = (start_date..end_date).each_with_object({}) { |d,h| h[d] = d + ':' }
  #=> {"2019-10-05"=>"2019-10-05:", "2019-10-06"=>"2019-10-06:",
  #    "2019-10-07"=>"2019-10-07:", "2019-10-08"=>"2019-10-08:",
  #    "2019-10-09"=>"2019-10-09:", "2019-10-10"=>"2019-10-10:",
  #    "2019-10-11"=>"2019-10-11:", "2019-10-12"=>"2019-10-12:",
  #    "2019-10-13"=>"2019-10-13:"}
```

Now we will loop through the elements `inst` (instances of `Order`) of `arr`, and for each will alter the value of the key in `h` that equals `inst.date` converted to a string:

```
arr.each do |inst|
  date = inst.date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
  h[date] += "#{h[date][-1] == ':' ? '' : ','} id #{inst.id}"
end
```

Resulting in:

```
h #=> {"2019-10-05"=>"2019-10-05:",
  #    "2019-10-06"=>"2019-10-06:",
  #    "2019-10-07"=>"2019-10-07: id 1",
  #    "2019-10-08"=>"2019-10-08: id 2",
  #    "2019-10-09"=>"2019-10-09:",
  #    "2019-10-10"=>"2019-10-10: id 3, id 4",
  #    "2019-10-11"=>"2019-10-11:",
  #    "2019-10-12"=>"2019-10-12: id 5",
  #    "2019-10-13"=>"2019-10-13:"}
```

All that remains is to extract the values of the hash `h`:

```
h.values
  #=> ["2019-10-05:",
  #    "2019-10-06:",
  #    "2019-10-07: id 1",
  #    "2019-10-08: id 2",
  #    "2019-10-09:",
  #    "2019-10-10: id 3, id 4",
  #    "2019-10-11:",
  #    "2019-10-12: id 5",
  #    "2019-10-13:"]
```